# Obtener el value de un select entre multiples select en html5

Tags: jquery, html5

tengo una duda, a ver si me pueden dar una manito.
Tengo un table con varios items, cada uno tiene 1 select con 2 opciones de pago, efectivo y tarjeta, lo que necesito es que cuando se cambie la opcion, me muestre el value de ese combo que cambió con JQuery.

Aca les dejo lo que hice en html5:

```
 <td>
 <select name="FormaDePago" id="">
 <option value="Tarjeta">Tarjeta</option>
 <option value="Efectivo">Efectivo</option>
 </select>
 </td>
```

Y aca lo que vengo haciendo con Jquery:

```
$(document).ready(function () { 

   $(".FormaDePago").change(function(){

      let formaPago = $(this).val();
      alert(formaPago);
      });
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Pues tienes el código completamente bien, pero lo que estás teniendo es un error de concepto.

En tu **Jquery** estás tratando de asociar un evento **change** a un elemento que tenga la clase **FormaDePago**:

**JQUERY**

```
 $(".FormaDePago").change(function(){
```

¿Qué es lo que ocurre? Que en tu **HTML** careces de elementos con la clase **FormaDePago** pero tienes un elemento con nombre **FormaDePago**.

Lo más sencillo sería incluir en tu **HTML** la clase a la que estás referenciando desde tu código **Jquery**, quedando así:

**HTML**

```
<td>
    <select name="FormaDePago" id="" class="FormaDePago">
        <option value="Tarjeta">Tarjeta</option>
        <option value="Efectivo">Efectivo</option>
    </select>
</td>
```